# EJB Query Language vs HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, ejb, hql

Is the EJB Query Language (EQL) the same as Hibernate Query Language (HQL)?

I'm reading a book entitled Enterprise Java Beans 3.0  by Bill Burke and it refers to it as EQL.

Are they actually the same thing, just one for EJB and one for Hibernate?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EJB Query Language is a standard query language built to be used by JPA implementations (also known as JPQL), if the ORM you're using is JPA compliant, then that query language will be supported, so the idea behind it is that you should be able to change your JPA implementation without having to change your queries.

On the other hand HQL is hibernate-specific and if you dont use hibernate as JPA implementation then probably your queries wont work.

Answer (score 2):

HQL is a superset of EQL (or JPQL). It contains additional functions and constructs, but they're basically the same. There are some features of JPQL that Hibernate doesn't implement yet, also.

Comment: Hibernate is a certified JPA provider.  As such it passes the TCK which tests, amongst other things, a providers compliance with JPQL parsing/handling.  So what does Hibernate not support in JPQL?